# Склонение слова «кони»

Tags: грамотная-речь, склонение, существительные

Как пишется слово "кони" в предложном падеже: "конями" или "коньми"?

Comment: Вы вообще о знаках препинания и о том, что предложение начинается с большой буквы, представление имеете? Править пришлось у Вас - КАЖДОЕ слово.

Comment: вообщето это ЧАТ а не уроки

Comment: Компьютер всетаки

Comment: а так нас учили конечно

Comment: Ярослав, вы крепко ошибаетесь. Это не уроки, но и не чат. А писать надо стараться грамотно и в чате. Одно дело, когда ошибка случайная (сам их пложу без меры), совсем другое - сознательная безграмотность на форуме русского языка.  

Кстати, надеюсь, что кроме слова "чат", вам знакомо ещё и слово "модератор".

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть: и качество вопроса, и уровень «верного» ответа недопустимы. Комментарии справедливы и хлёстки, но ими можно пожертвовать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, падежи учить надо! Вопросы к ним особенно... Во-вторых: "И где ж тебя так образовали?" "Коньми"- даже в страшном сне такой "авторский неологизм" трудно представить - не то, что в жизни... :)

Comment: так бабушка думала мама сказала также

Comment: Знаки препинания у вас тоже к бабушке пошли?

Answer (score 3):

*"Коньми" ― даже в страшном сне такой "авторский неологизм" трудно представить ― не то, что в жизни... :)* [из ответа Олеси]

**1.** Я бы не стала выражаться столь категорично.

Из книги Н. Еськовой "[Нормы русского литературного языка **XVIII—XIX веков**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=uV5EDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA668&lpg=PA668&dq=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B8&source=bl&ots=J7_ueLgKkF&sig=edKUEaqR3f0mDPwnBGka8MFBPYc&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjM-tX1xonfAhWhk4sKHZr_BkcQ6AEwCXoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B8&f=false)":
**КОНЬ** *тв. мн.* коня́ми
| КОНЬ *тв. мн.* коньми́
Бегут рассеянно враждебные народы,
Бегут без памяти, падут с коньми́ с гор в воды.
*Сумароков, Хорев, 1747.*

Зверьми́, ногтьми́, когтьми́ ― **так** говорили в **то** время.

**2.** А **так** писали классики ещё в прошлом веке.

*Под Стырью с **коньми** расстались.*
[М. Шолохов. Донские рассказы (сборник)](https://www.booksite.ru/fulltext/1/001/003/125/065.txt) [1927]

**3.** Да, конечно, творительный падеж, а не предложный.

**4.** Да, вполне возможны чисто бесполые ассоциации (животное-то издали одно и то же):
лошадь (ж. р., ед. ч.) ― лошади (мн. ч.) ― лошадя́ми и лошадьми́ (тв. п.);
конь (м. р., ед. ч.) ― кони (мн. ч.) ― коня́ми и коньми́ (тв. п.).

**5.** Итог: лошадки в настоящее время (в **современном** русском языке) остались в двух вариантах (лошади — *лошадя́ми* и *лошадьми́*), а ко́ники ― только в одном (кони ― ***коня́ми***).

Answer (score 2):

Кони (именительный падеж),
коней (родительный падеж),
коням (дательный падеж),
коней (винительный падеж),
конями (творительный падеж),
конях (предложный падеж).