# С плеч, с плечей

Tags: грамотная-речь, падежи

Меч - голова с плеч. А ношу сбрасываем с плечей.
Как обосновать окончания?

Comment: А где Вы видели  "ношу сбрасываем с плечей" ?

Comment: Здесь-https://youtu.be/obEdDGU3R0c

Comment: Странно, что "игра стоит свеч",  а вот ныне, если прикупить, то "свечей".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот что написано в словаре [Ушакова](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/938658) (**1935-1940**):
**плечо́**
плеча́, мн. пле́чи (плеча́ *устар.*), **плеч** (**плече́й** *устар.*), плеча́м (пле́чам *обл.*), плеча́ми (плечьми́ *устар.*), плеча́х (пле́чах *обл.*), ср.

[Мой меч — твоя голова с плеч](https://folklor.academic.ru/962/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%87_-_%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%8F_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D1%81_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%87). Как гора с плеч свалилась.

*— Не хочешь — не надо. Но мы, бабы, иной раз помогаем **сбросить ношу с плеч...***
М. Горький. Жизнь Клима Самгина

Ещё в сороковые годы прошлого века форма "с плечей" считалась устаревшей.

[У Тургенева: *Ее губы были немножко широки и бледны, плеча немного высоки.*
Возможно, такая форма была образована от древнерусского [плече](https://semenov.academic.ru/975/%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BE).]

**Дополнение**
Про особенности изменения слова **плечо** рассказано в книге Н. Еськовой "Нормы русского литературного языка XVIII—XIX веков": [плеча́](https://books.google.ee/books?id=uV5EDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA136&lpg=PA136&dq=%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B%20%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%20XVIII%E2%80%94XIX%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2&source=bl&ots=J7_ylHfIkL&sig=ACfU3U3fcKtLFPZmRzz6IYDr3ibfkSXucA&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjTvpWpkpHgAhVtlYsKHcoWDasQ6AEwAnoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B%20%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%20XVIII%E2%80%94XIX%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2&f=false) и [плечьми́](https://books.google.ee/books?id=uV5EDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA669&lpg=PA669&dq=%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B%20%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%20XVIII%E2%80%94XIX%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2&source=bl&ots=J7_ylHfFkF&sig=ACfU3U0YPB83FTIvYi-m0xAPtN-XG8MbkA&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwijtMeXkZHgAhWsiaYKHQf-AmEQ6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B%20%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%20XVIII%E2%80%94XIX%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2&f=false).

Answer (score 3):

Вариант ***плеч*** - норма, рекомендуется Словарём ударений Ф.Агеенко и М. Зарвы, Кратким словарём трудностей русского языка Н. Еськовой и Орфографическим словарём В. Лопатина.

Плечи, плеч, плечАм, плечАми, о плечАх... За плЕчи.

Плечей - устаревшее:

Словарь русского языка в 4-х т. / РАН, Ин-т лингвистич. исследований; Под ред. А. П. Евгеньевой. — 4-е изд., стер. — М.: Рус. яз.; Полиграфресурсы, 1999:

> ПЛЕЧО́, -а́, мн. пле́чи, плеч, плеча́м и (устар.) плеча́, плече́й

https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BE

Comment: А в чем причиры такой вариативности? Кажется, вопрос именно об этом.

Comment: Нет вариативности, есть просторечный ненормированный вариант, т.е. ошибка   http://rus-yaz.niv.ru/doc/phraseological-dictionary/articles/640/sbrasyvat-s-plech.htm   https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/es/141734/%D1%81%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C

Comment: Людмила, как крокодила ни называй, он останется крокодилом: в чем причина наличия такого "просторечного ненормированного (с чего вы взяли?! почитайте МАС!) варианта"?

Comment: Суть я понял - устаревшая форма. В разговоре люди зачастую позволяют себе употреблять подобное по старой памяти, а в поэзии - для рифмы и красоты слога. Спасибо большое всем, не прошедшим мимо участникам!

Comment: @|Aer, Вы хотели, чтоб я сказала, что плечи - это остаток двойственного числа, а плечА - множ. число? Тогда придётся вдаваться в подробности изменения категории падежа, а это, по-моему, ненужная глубина. Плечей - ещё и влияние склонения старославянского плеште, диалект в общем. А устаревшие слова - пассивный состав языка, употребляется часто как просторечие и как стилизация в поэзии - это верно.

Comment: Вот интересно,  все эти авторы писали на диалекте? Легкое пожатие кельнерских плечей, ― и мы опять на улице. [М. И. Цветаева.  (1934)] Меня каждый раз поражала в эту минуту её юность, тонкость: схваченный корсетом стан, лёгкое и такое непорочно-праздничное платьице, обнажённые от перчаток до плечей и озябшие,.[И. А. Бунин. Жизнь Арсеньева. Юность (1927-1933)]..с пожимом плечей он читает Чехова, не принимает Горького, не понимает Фета; подчеркивает болезненность в Достоевском..[Андрей Белый. (1930)]

Comment: Нет, они не писали на диалекте, они использовали устаревшие формы в качестве стилизации, чтобы подчеркнуть старорусскую интеллигентность рассказчиков. А вот если мы с Вами в быту, на сайте, в ЕГЭ  будем употреблять "плечей" - это будет речевая ошибка, вон даже Ворд подчёркивает красным.

Answer (score 2):

Согласно словарям, форма ***с плечей*** устарела, но в современных художественных произведениях она встречается.

**Неужели это все неграмотно написанные тексты,** если известно, что ещё в сороковые годы прошлого века форма "с плечей" считалась устаревшей?

**Или как это объяснить?**  Почему раньше использовались обе формы, а потом одна вдруг устарела?

**Примеры**

Два матроса в лесу Обращаются к ветру и сумраку, Рассекают листву Темной кожей широких **плечей**. [Виктор Пелевин. Чапаев и пустота (1996)]

Вот он обреченно осел, вжался меж двух черных камней, втянул голову в крупные кости **плечей**. [Виктор Астафьев. Последний поклон (1968-1991)]

Из-за **плечей** рослых москвичей все время выпрыгивал какой-то черный десантник. [Василий Аксенов. Остров Крым (авторская редакция) (1977-1979)]

― Владимир Генрихович встал, опираясь на трость, остервенело сорвал **с плечей** Алисы шубу. [Андрей Житков. Супермаркет (2000)]

Comment: Читал когда-то книгу Э. Скобелева " Мирослав - князь дреговичский". Там процентов семьдесят устаревших слов. Авторы, тем более популярные, многое себе позволяют, не считая это ошибкой. И правильно делают, на мой взгляд.

Comment: @Sharon Недавно я отвечала на похожий вопрос (некоторые участники даже голосовали за его закрытие, посчитав, наверно, банальным): **коньми и конями**. (https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/2931/Склонение-слова-кони ) А ведь оказалось не так все просто, как думалось. Примеры Ваши, конечно, классические. Ну-у, что дозволено Юпитеру... Может быть, это новое веяние в сторону старого?

Comment: В Грамматике-80  слово "плечо" выделено в отдельную акцентную группу, оно особенное. Здесь нужен анализ явления на уровне современного языка, а не отсыл к старославянскому и поспешные выводы. Сказать, что устарело, что диалект и просторечие - это нетрудно, сложнее понять развитие языка в наше время. В словаре Аванесова (1987) форма "плечей"  не рекомендуется к употреблению (мне она тоже напрягает слух),  но почему в 19 -20  вв. она свободно использовалась грамотными людьми?